# Getting typescript error in a react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

Getting this error at 2nd line of the code where i am trying to import stripe.

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'typeof import("stripe")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

```
("use strict");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);
/**
 * order controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::order.order", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async create(ctx) {
    const { products } = ctx.request.body;
    try {
      const lineItems = await Promise.all(
        products.map(async (product) => {
          const item = await strapi
            .service("api::product.product")
            .findOne(product.id);

          return {
            price_data: {
              currency: "usd",
              product_data: {
                name: item.title,
              },
              unit_amount: Math.round(item.price * 100),
            },
            quantity: product.quantity,
          };
        })
      );

      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        shipping_address_collection: { allowed_countries: ["US", "CA"] },
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: process.env.CLIENT_URL + "?success=true",
        cancel_url: process.env.CLIENT_URL + "?success=false",
        line_items: lineItems,
      });

      await strapi
        .service("api::order.order")
        .create({ data: { products, stripeId: session.id } });

      return { stripeSession: session };
    } catch (error) {
      ctx.response.status = 500;
      return { error };
    }
  },
}));
```

This is my file where i am getting the error while trying to integrate stripe payments with my app!
Also i am getting another error at
`const { products } = ctx.request.body;`

> Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'.ts(2339)

Please someone help!

tried importing stripe without the stripe key but still getting error when i am trying to do payment on my app

Comment: Are you running your code as Javascript or Typescript? How did you install stripe? I am asking these questions because your code is in Javascript, but you are receiving Typescript errors.

Comment: The [stripe instructions for Typescript](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage-with-typescript) seem to be different than what you have here. You almost never want to use `require` in a typescript application.

Comment: I installed stripe using npm also i am running the code using js

Comment: Actually i am making a react web application and the backend is completely handled by strapi but i have the add the payment in my application so i am editing this backend file

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is due to TypeScript's static type checking. The require("stripe") function returns a type of typeof import("stripe"), which TypeScript doesn't recognize as callable.

To fix this, you need to import the Stripe module in a way that TypeScript understands. Here's how you can do it:

```
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);
```